# How to set input value to current day in reflex?

Tags: haskell, frp, reflex, obelisk

I am using `reflex-platform` with `obelisk`.
This is my frontend code to get the current date

```
pb <- getPostBuild
postBuildTime <- performEvent $ pb $> liftIO getCurrentTime
let today = Text.pack . formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%F" <$> postBuildTime
```

I can confirm that this works by putting

```
dynText =<< holdDyn "loading" today
```

which does not even display "loading" for a split second but instead shows "2021-03-26" as expected in the browser (Google Chrome).

However, trying to put the `today` event into an `<input>` doesn't work. This is the code:

```
foo <- inputElement $ def & inputElementConfig_setValue .~ today
```

The `<input>` stays blank.

Even weirder: In my actual code the `<input>` has an initial value via `inputElementConfig_initialValue .~ "BAAAR"`, which doesn't show either. Yet a dynamic text created like

```
dynText =<< holdDyn "" foo
```

DOES show "BAAAR" for a split second.

---

And to calm any paranoia, I tested the `inputElementConfig_setValue` with a simple button, which worked fine. I.e. I can set the value of `<input>` by clicking on a button.

So the `postBuildTime` event works and the `inputElementConfig_setValue` works, but the combination of the two leaves the `<input>` blank.

EDIT

Minimal example including instructions on how to run and screenshot of the result:

[https://github.com/rubenmoor/reflex-bug-pbtime](http://github%20repo:%20reflex-bug-pbtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom/commit/93f0f4bd00e1dc871d193d7d53d5d7f2dbb518af

Looks like this was a bug, that has been fixed in `reflex-dom`.